# SQL like summarize reports using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I often produce in R single statement summarize reports using dplyr as the following:

```
a <- group_by(data,x) 
b <- summarise(a, 
                 # count distinct y where value is not missing
                 y_distinct = n_distinct(y[is.na(y) == F]),
                 # count distinct z where value is not missing
                 z_distinct = n_distinct(z[is.na(z) == F]),
                 # count total number of values
                 total = n(),
                 # count y where value not missing
                 y_not_missing = length(y[is.na(y) == F]),
                 # count y where value is missing
                 y_missing = length(y[is.na(y) == T]))
```

which is similar to the way I would produce it in SQL:

```
select
    count(distinct(case when y is not null then y end)) as y_distinct,
    count(distinct(case when z is not null then z end)) as z_distinct,
    count(1) as total,
    count(case when y is not null then 1 end) as y_not_missing,
    count(case when z is not null then 1 end) as y_missing
from data group by x
```

however, I'm (Python newbie and) not able to find the Panda's equivalent, and got lost in the documentation.
I'm able to produce each aggregation using a different  groupby ->  agg statements, 
but need help to produce the report in a single data frame (preferably using a single statement).

Comment: Ca you add data sample?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   x    y    z
0  1  2.0  NaN
1  1  3.0  NaN
2  2  NaN  1.0
3  2  NaN  2.0
4  3  4.0  5.0

In [19]: def nulls(s):
    ...:     return s.isnull().sum()
    ...:

In [23]: r = df.groupby('x').agg(['nunique','size',nulls])

In [24]: r
Out[24]:
        y                  z
  nunique size nulls nunique size nulls
x
1       2    2   0.0       0    2   2.0
2       0    2   2.0       2    2   0.0
3       1    1   0.0       1    1   0.0
```

In order to flatten columns:

```
In [25]: r.columns = r.columns.map('_'.join)

In [26]: r
Out[26]:
   y_nunique  y_size  y_nulls  z_nunique  z_size  z_nulls
x
1          2       2      0.0          0       2      2.0
2          0       2      2.0          2       2      0.0
3          1       1      0.0          1       1      0.0
```

Comment: You forget for groupby I guess.

Comment: @jezrael, yes, it's fixed now

Comment: thanks! does this answer entails that you will always use all aggregators on each of the columns? is that that really scalable? what if we have 100 columns and require a different aggregation on each?

Comment: @kamashay, you can always specify a list of columns that should be processed: `df.groupby('x')[list_of_cols].agg(...)` or `df[list_of_cols].groupby('x').agg(...)`

Comment: @MaxU ,but does that mean you would have to split the single report to N groupby-agg statements (again, computational overhead), resulting with N mini reports  - how would you connect them into a single report? afterwards? is there really no single groupby-agg statement to handle this?

Comment: @kamashay, please post a small reproducible sample data set and your desired report (data set)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need aggregation by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with functions - [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count all values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for count non `NaN`s values, [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) for count `unique` and custom function for count `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[4,np.nan,4,5,5,4],
                   'z':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'x':list('aaaabb')})

print (df)
   x    y    z
0  a  4.0  NaN
1  a  NaN  8.0
2  a  4.0  9.0
3  a  5.0  4.0
4  b  5.0  2.0
5  b  4.0  3.0



f = lambda x: x.isnull().sum()
f.__name__ = 'non nulls'
df = df.groupby('x').agg(['nunique', f, 'count', 'size'])
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   y_nunique  y_non nulls  y_count  y_size  z_nunique  z_non nulls  z_count  \
x                                                                             
a          2          1.0        3       4          3          1.0        3   
b          2          0.0        2       2          2          0.0        2   

   z_size  
x          
a       4  
b       2
```

Comment: thanks! I guess that your answer is similar to MaxU's answer - same comment apply - can you set a different aggregator to each of the columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use `.agg({'a':'nunique', 'b':'sum', ...})` or also more function for one column like `.agg({'y': ['nunique', f, 'count', 'size'], 'z':'sum'})`

Comment: More information is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns)

Comment: thanks, this may be the single statement solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the SQL query, you can use `pandasql` module to apply an `SQL` query directly on a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandasql as ps
query = """select
    count(distinct(case when y is not null then y end)) as y_distinct,
    count(distinct(case when z is not null then z end)) as z_distinct,
    count(1) as total,
    count(case when y is not null then 1 end) as y_not_missing,
    count(case when z is not null then 1 end) as y_missing
from df group by x""" #df here is the name of the DataFrame
ps.sqldf(query, locals())
```